# How-to insert Image into Hyperlink in GWT

Tags: java, image, gwt, hyperlink

Is there a way to make a clickable Image in GWT?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you could do to insert the `Image` in the `Hyperlink`:

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
Image image = new Image(someUrl);
...
link.getElement().appendChild(image.getElement());
```

To make the `Image` clickable you simply add a `ClickHandler` to it.

Comment: Neither yours nor Makkes' anwer adequately answers OP. I am sure he is aware that he can bind a clickhandler to do the same, I think he was looking for a non-JS dependent way to do so..

Answer (score 5):

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
Image image = new Image(someUrl);
...
link.getElement().getFirstChild().appendChild(image.getElement());
```

would be correct. Otherwise the image is added after the hyperlink

Comment: Can also use .getElement().insertFirst(Element)

Answer (score 4):

Just attach a ClickHandler to the image:

```
Image img = new Image(URL);
img.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent ev) {
    // do sth.
  }
};
```

That's it. The image is clickable. To indicate the clickability to the user just use an appropriate CSS style like cursor:pointer.

Answer (score 3):

```
    Anchor anchor = new Anchor();
    anchor.getElement().getStyle().setCursor(Cursor.POINTER); 
    anchor.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(ClickEvent ev) {
              Window.Location.assign("http://url.com");
          }
    });
    Image img = new Image("image/path.jpg");
    anchor.getElement().appendChild(img.getElement());
```

Use Anchor instead of HyperLink because addClickHandler is depreciated in HyperLink. The second line adds the hand pointer to the cursor when you hover the image. The rest is self explanatory I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a `ToggleButton` and apply some css styling. Then you have already all the `ClickHandler` support included.

Answer (score 1):

From a general point of view.. We can write an onclick event for the image and a css cursor: pointer (optional) to give it a hyperlink feel.